# python gettin a value from a file

Tags: python

I am a new python learner and I want to write a program which reads a text file, and save value of a line contains "width" and print it. 
The file looks like:

```
width:               10128
nlines:               7101
```

I am trying  something like:

```
filename = "text.txtr"

# open the file for reading
filehandle = open(filename, 'r')
while True:
    # read a single line
    line = filehandle.readline()
    if " width " in line:
        num = str(num)  # type:
        print (num)
    # close the pointer to that file
filehandle.close()
```

Comment: perhaps you could post what your result was? It helps others to help you

Comment: Okay, What's the problem and what did you expect.

Comment: it doesn't give back anything, but I am expecting the correct value of 10128

Comment: why space here  for search string width  `if " width " in line:`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your approach to opening the file is not good, try using with statement whenever opening a file. Afterwards you can iterate over each line from the file and check if it contains width, and if it does you need to extract the number, which can be done using regex. See the code below.

```
import re

filename = "text.txtr"


with open(filename, 'r') as filehandle:
    # read a single line
    for line in filehandle:
        if "width" in line:
            num = re.search(r'(\d+)\D+$', line).group(1)
            num = str(num)  # type:
            print (num)
```

Please see Matt's comment below for another solution to get the number.

Comment: As per the comment in pasted code: `# read a single line`. Also regex seems a bit overkill here! `num = line.split()[1]` would do the same job.

Comment: thanks. How can I modify re.search If I have a decimal number and line looks like: corner_lat:     49.0425000  decimal degrees

Comment: Try this re.search(r'\d+\.\d+$', line).group(1)

Answer (score 1):

This is a simplified way based on Muhamad's one.

What you need is:

- open a file
- read lines until you find "width" in one
- extract the number that follows a colon
- close the file
- print the number

It Python it can give

```
num = None                     # "sentinel" value
with open(file) as fd:         # with will ensure file is closed at end of block
    for line in fd:            # a Python open file is an iterator on lines
        if "width" in line:    # identify line of interest
            num = int(line.split(':')[1])    # get the number in the second part of
                                             # the line when it is splitted on colons
            break              # ok, line has been found: stop looping

if num is not None:            # ok we have found the line
    print(num)
```

Answer (score 0):

It's not returning results because of the line `if " width " in line:`.

As you can see from your file, there is not a line with `" width "` in there, maybe you want:

```
 if "width:" in line:
      #Do things
```

Also note there are a few issues with the code, for example that your program will never finish becasuse of your line `While True:`, so you'll never actually reach the line `filehandle.close()` and the manner which you open the file (using `with` is preferred). Also that you are defining `num = str(num)` but num isn't already defined so you will run into issues there too.

Answer (score 0):

Fist of all no need to hold the file in a variable better directly open the file with `with open` method it takes care of file closing once read/write operation are done on the `self_exit()` function.

So, you can start & clean your code like below:

```
with open("text.txtr", "r") as fh:
    lines = fh.readlines()
    for line in lines:
       if 'width' in line:
           print(line.strip())
```